# Unexpected output in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

On executing the query

```
select * from employee
where salary <= previous_salary
```

I'm getting a wrong output as follows (it's returning the entire table).  I'm doing this in Oracle Application Express Edition

```
ID  NAME    SALARY  DEPT    PREVIOUS_SALARY
1   nadeem  1000    10      1500
2   kutu    1000    10      1500
3   aisha   1500    20      500
4   aisha   1500    20      500
```

and on executing this query

```
select * from employee
where salary >= previous_salary
```

I get no data found.

Comment: Please note that the guesswork would be removed if you included the schema of your table (type information) in the question.

Comment: thanks a million for he answer sir i was sitting at this same error for nearly 2 days thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please note that the way to say 'thanks' around here is via up-votes for helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to give them), and by bestowing an 'accept' on the most helpful answer (which you can always do for questions you've asked, and which also gives you a small boost to your own reputation).  See also the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work "How does “Reputation” work?") and [this piece](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") of FAQ in particular.

Comment: @user1129400: please remember to post your table definitions the next time you ask a question like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've probably used a CHAR or VARCHAR2 type for the SALARY and PREVIOUS_SALARY columns.

When compared as strings, the data *should* work as you claim it does.

If you change the columns containing numbers to a numeric type, then the numeric comparisons will work as you intended.

Comment: +1 Or compared `to_number(salary) >= to_number(previous_salary)` - but if it's possible to change the datatypes to numeric, these should definitely be numeric!

Comment: Good catch. And it shows how important it is to include the full table definition in the question.